# How to insert hidden filed value into database using ajax jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, field, hidden

Can anyone help me, i have a form with major_id set as hidden, when i't trying to submit my form i am not getting the major_id value into my database. I'm really new into this i dont know what to do. I know thers something wrong with my jquery

```
    $(function() {

    $(".button").click(function() {


    var major_id = $("input[name='major_id']").val('1');
    var titlesBg = $("#titlesBg").val();
    var subBg = $("#subBg").val();
    var smp = $("#smp").val();
    var sbu = $("#sbu").val();
    var dataString =  { 'major_id': major_id , 'titlesBg': titlesBg , 'subBg': subBg , 'smp': smp , 'sbu': sbu };



$sql_check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM sub_guidelines username =" . $_SESSION['username'] . "order by sub_id desc");

if(isSet($_POST['titlesBg']) || ($_POST['subBg']) || ($_POST['smp']) || ($_POST['sbu']))

{
$major_id = $_GET['major_id'];
$titlesBg = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['titlesBg']);
$subBg = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['subBg']);
$smp = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['smp']);
$sbu = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['sbu']);
$username = $_SESSION['username'];


mysql_query("insert into sub_guidelines(username, major_id, titlesBg, subBg, smp, sbu) values ('$username','$major_id','$titlesBg','$subBg','$smp','$sbu')");

$sql_in= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM sub_guidelines WHERE username = '$username' AND major_id = '$major_id' order by sub_id desc");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($sql_in);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

it easy:

```
var major_id = $("input[name='major_id']").val('1');
```

will set the value of the hiddden field to 1, not return the value of the hidden field ;)
this will return a jquery object ;)

```
var major_id = $("input[name='major_id']").val();
```

returns the value

so:

you send your data with the post method but try to get major_id with get.
this should help:

```
$major_id = $_POST['major_id'];
```

and i'msorry but this is totaly wrong:

```
if(isSet($_POST['titlesBg']) || ($_POST['subBg']) || ($_POST['smp']) || ($_POST['sbu']))
```

you have to check ever value for its own

```
if(isset($_POST['titlesBg']) || isset($_POST['subBg']) || isset($_POST['smp']) || isset($_POST['sbu']))
```

besides, i would use a logical AND not an OR ;)

Comment: i changed it to var major_id = $("input[name='major_id']").val(); but still im getting 0 in my major_id column in my datbase. :(

Comment: do you have the HTML code for us? and maybe the script that sends the value to the db?

Comment: there i just posted the codes that sends the value. all other value is okay just except for the major_id. :(